# ftplib file select

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

Manual says

> To download a file, use ftp.retrlines('RETR ' + filename)

Here is what i do:

```
ftp.retrbinary('RETR media/backups/andrey.txt', open("file_to_get.txt", 'a+').write)
```

Could please someone advise how to put filename variable, previously added via raw_input, after the "RETR" command?
Used %s but this does not work, it gets processed like a part of a filename.

```
ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s', open("file_to_get.txt", 'a+').write) %raw_input("print file name")
```

produces this:

```
c:\>python ftp_client.py
Enter host95.31.8.52
drwxrwxrwx   61 99         102             32768 Sep 14 01:39 backpl
drwxrwxrwx   19 99         102              4096 Sep  7 13:47 media
drwxrwxrwx    2 99         102              4096 Jul  2 11:15 naswebsite
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ftp_client.py", line 12, in <module>
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s', open("file_to_get.txt", 'a+').write) %raw_input("p
rint file name")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 399, in retrbinary
    conn = self.transfercmd(cmd, rest)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 361, in transfercmd
    return self.ntransfercmd(cmd, rest)[0]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 330, in ntransfercmd
    resp = self.sendcmd(cmd)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 244, in sendcmd
    return self.getresp()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 219, in getresp
    raise error_perm, resp
ftplib.error_perm: 550 Can't open %s: No such file or directory

c:\>
```

Comment: Please show how you're getting the filename and how you tried to use `%s` to do something with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work

```
filename = 'andrey.txt'
path = "media/backups/"
ftp.cwd(path)
ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + filename ,open(filename, 'a+').write)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Is there a way to make it eat up file path media/backups/andrey.txt without change directory command?
i guess that's how FTP works but maybe I'm wrong.