# Cannot open file in Python "No such file or directory" error

Tags: python, python-2.7, ftp, osx-mavericks

I've been trying to download files from an FTP server. For this I've found this [Python-FTP download all files in directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230966/python-ftp-download-all-files-in-directory) and examined it. Anyways, I extracted the code I needed and it shows as follows:

```
import os

from ftplib import FTP

ftp = FTP("ftp.example.com", "exampleUsername", "examplePWD")

file_names = ftp.nlst("\public_html")

print file_names

for filename in file_names:
    if os.path.splitext(filename)[1] != "":
        local_filename = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "Download", filename)
        local_file = open(filename, 'wb')
        ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + filename, local_file.write)
        local_file.close()

ftp.close()
```

But when it tries to open the file, it keeps saying:

```
ftplib.error_perm: 550 Can't open CHANGELOG.php: No such file or directory
```

I've tried `w+`, `a+`, `rw`, etc. and I keep getting the same error all the time. Any ideas?

Note: I am using OSX Mavericks and Python 2.7.5.

This question may have been asked several times and believe me I researched and found some of them and none of them worked for me.

1. [open() in Python does not create a file if it doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967194/python-open-does-not-create-file-if-it-doesnt-exist/2967291#2967291)
2. [ftplib file select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423501/ftplib-file-select)

Comment: This seems to be a maverick problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are listing files in a directory and then getting files based on the returned strings. Does nlst() return full paths or just filenames? If its just filenames than retrbinary might be expecting "/Foo/file" but getting "file", and there might not be anything named file in the root dir of the server.